# SQL: Getting the some by type in another table

Tags: sql

I am quite new to SQL and am currently trying to adjust to working with data in different tables. I would like to retrieve a singular SUM of a particular student's points.

(Therefore, each "Discipline_Student_ID"'s relevant "Discipline_Pointsch" must be added to the SUM that I want to return. (WHERE [specific student's ID])).
How would I go about joining the tables in my code to execute what I am trying to achieve?

(Thanks for the help!)  [image]

Comment: seems like a typical [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to me. can you please share what you've tried and researched so far? we'll gladly help if you're stuck somewhere, but you should first attempt to solve the task on your own - and be able to describe your efforts. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: MySql, Sqlite, and Sql Server are all very different database engines. Which one are you actually using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also need things from the `Student` table (like their name), you can do this:

```
SELECT s.Student_ID, s.Student_Name, coalesce(SUM(dt.Discipline_Pointsch),0) As Points
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Discipline d on d.Student_NWU_ID = s.Student_ID
LEFT JOIN Discipline_Type dt on dt.Discipline_Type_Code = d.Discipline_Type_Code
WHERE s.Student_ID = [specific students ID]
GROUP BY s.Student_ID, s.Student_Name
```

I chose LEFT (outer) joins instead of INNER joins, along with a coalesce operation, so you can see results for students who do not have any demerits.

You might also choose to simplify the `GROUP BY` portion, while making the query structure a little more complex, like this:

```
SELECT s.*, coalesce(p.Points) Points
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT Student_NWU_ID, SUM(Discipline_Pointsch) As Points
    FROM Discipline d
    INNER JOIN Discipline_Type dt on dt.Discipline_Type_Code = d.Discipline_Type_Code 
    GROUP BY Student_NWU_ID
) p ON p.Student_NWU_ID = s.Student_ID
WHERE s.Student_ID = [specific students ID]
```